# WCF duplex channel gets closed when using callbacks

Tags: wcf, callback, channel, duplex

My WCF service uses netTcpBinding, and has a callback object.

I need to service multiple concurrent clients, and mantain sessions, so the service is decorated with

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple]
```

To avoid thread deadlocks, the callback class is decorated with

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

and I use `SynchronizationContext` to execute the method in the UI thread.

The problem is that sometimes the channel gest closed with no reason (`ICommunicationObject.Closing` event gets fired). After that, I get exceptions in any subsequent service call.

Looking in the trace file, the last message is a callback call, however, the callback method never gets invoked. There are no exceptions.

After some debugging I identified that this happens only when the callback call is made in the middle of a synchronous operation. The steps would be this:

1. Call to service method `A` with `IsOneWay=true`
2. Call to service method `B` with `IsOneWay=false`
3. `A` invokes a callback method, but `B` is still executing.

This shouldn't be a problem because the callback has `UseSynchronizationContext=false`, so the callback call could be attended in a separate thread.

I was unable to reproduce the problem in a simpler scenario. Following these steps in a simple project executes successfully.

Any idea of what could be happening or how to identify the problem?

Comment: code snippets could be beneficial from client and service side.

Answer (score 10):

I think what's probably happening is the client is faulting the channel because it received the callback message when it was expecting the reply message. In WCF with net.tcp, callbacks and replies use the same channel.

As a rule, you should never call a callback method inside the body of a request/reply (IsOneWay=false) OperationContract method. The safest thing would be to not have any request/reply methods in your contract whatsoever when doing duplex, but you can safely have them just so long as they don't call back into the callback contract before returning. (It would be ok to call a callback method *after* returning, for example from another worker thread).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response!
I could solve the error.

It was a serialization problem, I added `IncludeExceptionsInFaults=true` in the service and callback behavior attribute, and then I was able to see the error.

The problem was that I was sending a DataTable with columns of type object.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this attribute on the top of WCF wrapper class:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

From cauldwell.net:

> The problem, it turned out, was that ASP.NET uses (by default) a little thing called the SynchronizationContext. As near as I can tell
>   (I haven't researched this thoroughly, to be honest) one of it's jobs
>   it to make sure that any callbacks get run on the UI thread, thereby
>   obviating the need to call Control.Invoke like you do in WinForms. In
>   my case, that additional lock was giving something fits, and it was
>   trying to clean stuff up on a thread that wasn't around any more,
>   hence to NullReferenceException.